# not being able to pass a data from flask to html template

Tags: python, html, variables, flask

I'm using a very simple code to pass data from flask to html template
but the value is not passed
here is mi code

python code:

```
 @app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST']) 
 def home():
     if request.method=='GET':
         return render_template("base.html")
 
     if request.method=='POST':
         
 
         print('hello')
         resultat="helo"
         a=True
         return render_template("base.html",resultat=resultat)
```

html code:

```
<p> {%if a %} {{ resultat }} {% endif %} </p>
```

can someone help me please

Comment: It seems that you are only returning the result on post.

Are you expecting a result on GET?

Comment: no , I want to pass a result only on post and when the post is done 'hello' is printed on the console but the variable result is displayed in the page html

Comment: see: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing a to the template.

```
return render_template("base.html", resultat=resultat, a=a)
```

Also, did you mean `result`?

Comment: i add the a=a but it still not working .....(yes ,result means resultat in french)

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

According to the documentation and my local testing it should work.

Try to debug by only returning the anticipated page with variables set and no other code.

Double check your template.

Comment: I think that the problem is only with post method because when I pass data on the get it works , but when i got information through post the hello is printed but no change in the html page is seen .

Comment: @fatima with `render_template(.., a=a)` it should work correctly - maybe better create minimal working code which we could run and see problem. Or maybe it loads different file `base.html` then you expect.

Comment: yes, thank you . i just figured out that it is not working because i m sending a post through javascript and javascript post does'nt do the redirection as form post

Comment: @fatima Correct. Please mark my answer as correct since it would have been another issue you encountered later on.